# iPhone: Is it possible to go back to the previous application after handling custom URL?

Tags: iphone, custom-url, x-callback-url

I know that iPhone applications can be launched via a custom URL such as myapp://something. But is there a way to go back to the previous application after handling the custom URL?

For example, I have the following scenario.

1. Follow a link from iPhone Twitter application.
2. Twitter shows a link that redirects to a custom URL.
3. My application is invoked and handles the URL.
4. After completing the job, I go back to the Twitter app.

I want my application to handle a custom URL like a modal dialog box. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this isn't officially supported, it is totally doable: take a look at the x-callback-url  spec. It's been implemented by several apps, like Due and Instapaper:

http://x-callback-url.com/

Comment: I have tried to implement this and cannot figure it out. I am running a script using Siri. That script makes an X-callback-URL call, that app opens (e.g. shortcuts), but I cannot figure out how to get it to go back to whatever app was on the screen when I Told Siri to run the shortcut. Am I not understanding how this is supposed to work or what use cases are supported? The examples in the linked dock, as I understand them, don't tell me how to do this. Can you quote the specific place that tells you how to go back to the original app when the shortcut was invoked?

Comment: My comment is from 12 years ago; at the time, x-callback-url was the best option available, but I don't know if that's still the case! I'd recommend searching the web to look for more-recent documentation / blog-posts on this.

Comment: Yes. Apparently, it's not technically possible to do (with x-callback-url) what I want to do: go back to whatever app was on the screen before the call. But, I have worked out a way to do it by adding personal automations that log the current app upon open of every most common app that I use. I save that in an iCloud Drive file and when I, want to go back to the previous app, I just look up the current app in that file

Comment: Incidentally, regarding my comment "I cannot figure out how to get it to go back to whatever app was on the screen when I Told Siri to run the shortcut", I think I realized that when called from Shortcuts, the "sourceApp" that is referred to in the docs is probably "Shortcuts", as opposed to whatever app is on the screen when I issue the command with 'Hey Siri'. Besides, I don't think there exists a referential way to refer to "sourceApp", i.e. "self". My work-around is here: https://www.reddit.com/r/shortcuts/comments/pfzonj/comment/ki06f37/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Answer (score 1):

That I guess is not possible unless both apps are yours and you implement a custom url for each other.

Answer (score 0):

The method that you use to handle launching app from a custom URL has a param called source application which gives you info about the bundle ID of the app that launched your app. Maybe try using that to launch the calling app again.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
```